# Strange behaviour in std::async

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, std

I want have one task that can be killable if it's running of time.

So i am tryng this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto handle = std::async(std::launch::deferred,[]
                        {
                            cout<<"Initializing thread..."<<endl; 
                            this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
                        }
                );

    cout<<"Starting..."<<endl;
    handle.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    cout<<"Finished correctly"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The ouput:

> Starting...
>
> Finished correctly

Why don't print "Initializing thread..."? I tried swap both chronos and doesn't works anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never demand the result of the task, so it isn't scheduled.

Replace `deferred` with `async` and you'll get what you expect.

Comment: The point is, if i create a thread, i will not able to kill it

Comment: The important thing there is, you cannot create a thread with `std::async`. You do not control that.

Answer (score 1):

`deferred` only evaluates on a *non*-timed `wait` function. If you change to:

```
handle.wait();
```

You'll see the thread start at that point.

Comment: That's not what the OP wants to do though. Otherwise you could just call .get()